# Reverse dendrogram and heatmap ordering in seaborn clustermap

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

At the moment, seaborn clustermap seems to "ladderize" the dendrogram such that the branch with fewest children go to the top / left of the dendrogram. I simply want the row order (and column order) of the items to be reversed. How do I do this so that both the heatmap and the dendrogram have a reversed order?

Comment: can you provide minimum runnable code using some toy data?

Comment: The seaborn default example with iris data at https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.clustermap.html would be fine to use. Should I add that to the main question

Comment: It seems like I can just call `invert_xaxis()` and `invert_yaxis()` on `result.ax_heatmap`, `result.ax_row_dendrogram`, and `result.ax_col_dendrogram`